# Change YiiBooster widget generated URL

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-booster

I'm having this issue: when I render a widget using YiiBooster it works great, but the problem comes when that widget has for example an JsonGridCiew will generate a table with all my data and also the pagination menu. The pagination menu has a wrong URL to load the second page.

My project has a frontend and a backend, so my backend is inside the protected folder, the pagination widget tries to find the second page in the URL.

> localhost/site/quotes?Car_quote_page=10

But the correct URL is:

> localhost/backend.php/site/quote?Car_quote_page=10

How can I add the `backend.php` to the URL automatically?

Comment: about which url are u talking about? Because JsonGridView is just like a GridView just with additional pagination menu property. It just render the record in the list provided by $dataProvider. It does not call any url.

Comment: in the pagination menu, the numbers have an url to show the next rows, that's the url I'm talking about.

Comment: Does not it show anything on page10?

Comment: yeah, it show the url that I'm trying to change (localhost/site/quote?Car_quote_page=10) , what I want is that the yiibooster generate this url "localhost/backend.php/"... instead of localhost/site